# How to run cgminer on boot?

Tags: startup, raspberry-pi

I have the following commands I want to run when the raspberry pi boots up, it is for my bitcoin minner to start:

```
cd /home/pi/cgminer-4.5.0
sudo ./cgminer -o http://xxxxxxxxxxx -u xxxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx
```

How can I do this? As I have currently set it up using nohup but this only autostarts when I ssh into the pi and stops working when I close the connection. I want this code to run automatically on startup and keep running constantly. I am running Raspbian.

Comment: Crossposted from here http://askubuntu.com/questions/526323/how-to-run-a-script-on-boot

Comment: @steeldriver yes, I asked them to delete the AU one since it's off topic there and I suggested the OP post here instead.

Comment: Any reason why you should start cgminer with root permissions?

Comment: I have tried starting it without root permissions, but get the error no usb connected, by starting it in root fixes the error for some reason

Comment: I would recommend you to ask another question about that problem. cgminer should work fine without root privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the following code into :
`/etc/init.d/rc.local`:

```
/home/pi/cgminer-4.5.0/cgminer -o http://xxxxxxxxxxx -u xxxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks this seem to be working fine for me and so simple thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`nohup` should be okay for keeping it running upon disconnection. Maybe your problem is somewhere else.

If you want to run something on boot, you could conveniently use the `@reboot` tag in a `crontab` entry.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then add the line

```
@reboot /full/path/to/script.sh
```

This is run as root user. By the way, why `root`? And why mine on a raspi?